# Is there a difference between abstract vector spaces and vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

I am following my Oxford syllabus and my next step is *abstract vector spaces*, in my linear algebra book I've found *vector spaces*.

I've searched a little and made a superficial comparison between both and found that they are the same thing. Is that correct or there's something I'm missing? Also, if it's correct, why two names to the same thing?

Comment: They should be the same thing.

Comment: "Abstract vector spaces" emphasizes that the spaces in question need not be $\Bbb{C}^n$ (or $\Bbb{R}^n$).

Comment: @Micah Do you suggest some book in the topic?

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo Linear Algebra by Friedberg, Insel & Spence treats vector spaces over arbitrary fields. Also, you could possibly take a look at Chap. 11 in Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, but this of course might assume the previous chapters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am quite sure *vector spaces" and "abstract vector spaces" mean the same thing, and as Micah suggests, "abstract vector spaces" may simply make it more explicit that the spaces of concern are not necessarily $\mathbb C^n$ or $\mathbb R^n$. However, most courses and/or texts on linear algebra teach vector spaces as spaces which need not be $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$.

For example, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space), you can read:

> Vectors in vector spaces do not necessarily have to be arrow-like objects as they appear in the mentioned examples: vectors are best thought of as abstract mathematical objects with particular properties ...
>
> ...Historically, the first ideas leading to vector spaces can be traced back as far as 17th century's analytic geometry, matrices, systems of linear equations, and Euclidean vectors. The modern, more abstract treatment, first formulated by Giuseppe Peano in 1888, encompasses more general objects than Euclidean space...

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. :-)

Comment: In "Introduction to matrix computations" by G W Stewart they begin by describing properties of R^n, then later introduce an "abstract vector space V". The difference is that when discussing vectors in the abstract space, they do not discuss components of the vector, nor do proofs using the scalar components.  So the proof on page 8 is much more tedious. Proving b = 0 * a in R^n can be done be showing the same is true for each scalar component of the vector. The same proof for an abstract vector space will not use components of the vector, instead use other established properties of vector math

Comment: Basically, as far as I can tell, abstract vector spaces are more generalized, not having an *n* parameter, so proofs like assocutive properties cannot be proved based on showing the same for n scalar components. I'm not really sure the purpose, and this book basically abandons the concept, and says Rn is sufficient for their purposes.

Comment: Not sure if you can see this: https://books.google.com/books?id=XXzNCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA8#v=onepage&q&f=false